# Custom Post Type UI plugin show category hierarchical in URL

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I am using Custom Post Type UI Plugin and have added custom taxanomy named **"course_schedule"**

configuration as image at this link

http://jmp.sh/h8X5DwI

now than after i have created Custom Post Type with name **"course"**
configs as image in link bellow

http://jmp.sh/Yd8aScZ

now i am unable to achieve the slug as you can see in the bellow image
http://jmp.sh/RBFqOGn

Comment: You need to change this `%course_schedule%` to `course_schedule`

Comment: but it will statically show me course_schedule and not the category od taxonomy value which i have selected